# extjs 4 - how to add items into panel header?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to add `Ext.button.Split` into panel's header instead of title. It must be something like switcher of a panel's content and title of the same panel together. 
Is there any option in extjs 4 to do that? Or is there better solution instead of Split button? Unfortunately, switcher in panel header is the key requirement, so it must be placed there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below works for me ExtJs 4.2.2

```
{
            xtype: 'panel',
            ......

            header: {
                titlePosition: 0,
                items: [ 
                    {
                        xtype: 'splitbutton',

                    }
                ]
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the header object to your panel with your tools and add items for buttons.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    header: {
        // if you want your button positioned on the right hand side add
        // titlePosition: 0,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'splitbutton',
            text: 'test'
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops.. Peter Li was a little faster :/

Comment: probably because I typed less than you :)